# Problem with Bearer Authorization token in php curl

Tags: php, curl, authorization, token

When I try to post data with bearer token on https://reqbin.com there is no error. But I copy the code:

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.real-debrid.com/rest/1.0/unrestrict/link";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ZWP53ALWWN7*******GZHE66Z6BL54FV4Z2DWNS22URJUX6Q";
$headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = "link=https://rapidgator.net/file/6e3e93b5c15700c574b4313de8ad416f/";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

and try to run on my servers I get this error.

> string(43) "{ "error": "bad_token", "error_code": 8 }"

Comment: Looks like a problem of authentication. How did you obtain the authentication token?

Comment: Is your token correct? try fetching your user data first,  you can also send your token as a parameter in REST API URLs, the parameter is called auth_token:

/rest/1.0/method?auth_token=your_api_token

Comment: Yes it's my token. But it works on reqbin.com with same token.

Comment: please help. i tried two different hostings and localhost. it works on reqbin only. what is the differance?